# A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1048 Column 'gambar' cannot be null , upload file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

the method upload file is work perfectly but i can't save the data, maybe there is something with variable "gambar", i just can't understand how this upload file works. so please help me to fix it

[image]

controller :

```
public function add(){
    if($this->input->post('submit')){
        if($this->Console_model->validation("save")){
        $this->Console_model->create();
        if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<p  style="color:black">Console Succesfully Added!</p>');
        }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<p  style="color:red">Console Input Failed!</p>');
        }
        redirect('console');
        }
    }
    $data['specs']=$this->Spec_model->read();
    $data['view'] = "console/v_form";
    $this->load->view('index', $data);
}
```

model :

```
public function create(){
    $data=array(
        'nama_con' => $this->input->post('nama_con'),
        'garansi' => $this->input->post('garansi'),
        'deskripsi' => $this->input->post('deskripsi'),
        'harga' => $this->input->post('harga'),
        'gambar' => $this->input->post('gambar')
    );
    $this->gambar=$this->do_upload();
    $this->db->insert('tb_console',$data);
}

private function do_upload(){
    $config['upload_path']      = './uploads/barang/';
    $config['allowed_types']    = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']         = 4072;
    $config['max_width']        = 1024;
    $config['max_height']       = 768;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if($this->upload->do_upload('gambar')){
        return $this->upload->data('file_name');
    }
    return "default.jpg";
}
```

i have try to using the create method before i code the upload method and its works normal

view :

```
<?php
$nama="";$gar="";$desk="";$har="";$gam="";
    if(isset($con)){
        $nama=$con->nama_con;
        $gar=$con->garansi;
        $desk=$con->deskripsi;
        $har=$con->harga;
        $gam=$con->gambar;
    }
?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <form class="col-md-4 mx-auto" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <h2 class="mt-5 mb-5">Form Console</h2>
            <div style="color: red;"><?php echo validation_errors(); ?></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Nama">Nama Console</label>
                <select name="nama_con" class="form-control" id="">
                    <option value="">Choose Console</option>
                    <?php foreach($specs as $spec){ ?>
                    <option value="<?=$spec->name_con?>" <?=set_select('name_con', $spec->name_con, $nama==$spec->name_con?TRUE:FALSE)?>><?=$spec->name_con?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="garansi">Garansi</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="garansi" value="<?=$gar?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Deskripsi">Deskripsi</label>
                <textarea name="deskripsi" class="form-control" id=""><?=$desk?></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="harga">Harga</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="harga" value="<?=$har?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="fullname">Gambar</label>
                <input type="file" name="gambar" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success">
            <a href="<?=site_url('console')?>"><input type="button" value="Batal" class="btn btn-danger"></a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its cause your gambar value is null and your gambar field is not allowed null value, you may edit your field and give a check on null checkbox.

May you try to :

---

```
public function create()
{
  $this->gambar=$this->do_upload();
  $data=array(
          'nama_con' => $this->input->post('nama_con'),
          'garansi' => $this->input->post('garansi'),
          'deskripsi' => $this->input->post('deskripsi'),
          'harga' => $this->input->post('harga'),
          'gambar' => $this->gambar
        );
   $this->db->insert('tb_console',$data);
}
```

---

your pict name isn't from post, its from do_upload return i think

Comment: yes it's fix it , i forgot to mention but i have to use gambar value to display the file, in that case maybe i have to declare gambar as something else or i put gambar in uncorrect way but im not enough to understand that and also thanks for your help

Comment: its work but i have a little problem here, now gambar data uploaded as ''1'' in the database, can you help me to change it from ''1'' to filename

Comment: i think your $this->gambar is an array, try to debug using print_r($this->gambar),
I often use : 
$filename = $this->upload->data("file_name");
$filename = $filename['file_name']; //this is your image name result